# Pattern match any alphanumeric text before - in the string

Tags: regex

I try to get any alphanumeric word or text in a string before the negative sign `-` for example:

```
earth-green, random-stuff, coffee-stuff, another-tag
```

I try to match `earth random coffee another`

I tried the following regex:

```
(\w*[^][\-])
```

However, it matches `earth- random- coffee- another-`

[**This DEMO**](http://regexr.com/3avll) shows the situation. there you may notice that `earth- random- coffee- another-` are highlighted while I don't want include the negative sign `-` in the highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example to use positive look ahead regex.

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\w+)(?=-)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR3yH2/1)**

On the other hand, the problem in your regex was that you were putting the hypen and ^ within the capturing group:

```
(\w*[^][\-])
     ^---^---- Here (btw... you don't need [^])
```

You had to use this one instead

```
(\w+)-
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR3yH2/2)**

Comment: The website that you use in demos return timeout error during process expressions

Comment: I think your expression need to be `(\w*).(?=-)`. Check [this working demo](http://regexr.com/3avlr)

Comment: @sємsєм actually not, that page you are using is not trustable. You can see two working demos in my answer. I recommend you to use regex101 instead.

Comment: @sємsєм The page you are using get dizzied because of `\w*`. You can easily fix that using `\w+`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a word boundary and `-` to bookmark what you want:

```
\b(\w+)-
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA8mP4/1)

Comment: In regexr.com, your pattern also returns `-` with the matched characters.

Comment: No, you need to look at the match group, it does not contain the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = 'earth-green, random-stuff, coffee-stuff, another-tag'
>>> re.compile('(\w+)-\w+').findall(x)
['earth', 'random', 'coffee', 'another']
>>>
```

A lot of good examples with diverse use cases [regex howtos](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Comment: While this answer may answer the question, perhaps you could improve your answer by adding an explanation for what's going on and how this works so that rather than simply copying & pasting the solution, the asker might learn and be less likely to ask in the future.

Comment: I already see a fabulous! explanation above but it's a good thought, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can match it like this.

```
   my $string = "earth-green, random-stuff, coffee-stuff, another-tag";
    while ($string =~ m/[\w]*-/g)
    {
        my $temp = $&;
        $temp =~s/-//;
        print "$temp\n";
    }
```

Hope this helps.